# Why is there a call to mdelay(1) when resetting interrupt affinities?

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt

I'm trying to change the code that brings down a cpu, and got into something I don't completely understand:

One of the things that happen after a core is removed from cpu_online_mask, is the resetting of the interrupt affinities.
This is being done in the fixup_irqs() function, found in [/arch/x86/kernel/irq.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/irq.c#L361).
The function resets interrupt affinities, then calls to mdelay(1) (which simply waits for 1 millisecond), and finally turns to handle possibly "lost" interrupts.

My question is: why is the call to mdelay(1) necessary? what can happen without it? 
My guess is that it takes time for the rerouting in the APIC to take effect... but I'm sure that there is a more convincing explanation for this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are lucky, that could be added post 2.6.12 and if you do a `git blame` and find the commit that introduced that delay, there may be an explanation in the commit message.

Comment: @Shahbaz, yup, here possible explanation:  5231a68614b9.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko, if you mean [this](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=5231a68614b94f60e8f6c56bc6e3d75955b9e75e), then I don't think it gives the explanation. 

This commit just removes the interrupt_enable/disable that surrounds mdelay(1).  Namely, mdelay was there before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nut shell, there is a race condition in fixup_irq() - the function starts by going over all the IRQs routed to the CPU that is being offlined and tells the HW to route them to somewhere else.

The thing is, the process of changing this interrupt routing is not atomic or instantaneous. The transaction that changes the routing on the PIC chip might race with a transaction that sends an interrupt - and that might take some cycles to arrive, so you might end up with:

1. Tell the APIC to send interrupts to some other CPU, not me.
2. Interrupt!

So what the code does is basically:

1. Tell the APIC to send interrupts to some other CPU not me.
2. Wait a bit.Enough so that the interrupt re-route would be guaranteed to finalize. ( How to know how much time is enough to wait? maybe its documented in the APIC spec, maybe its internal knowledge some Intel VLSI engineer revealed to their Linux people - I don't know :-)
3. Check if an interrupt occurred by reading a register on the APIC that latches when an interrupt was sent and if you find any, send it to the proper target as an IPI.
4. Now we know no interrupt will really get to us.

Comment: Indeed - sounds reasonable. 
But if so - how can sending spurious interrupts provide an alternative to this approach?

As the comment in the code says: 

`We can remove mdelay() and then send spuriuous interrupts to new cpu targets for all the irqs that were handled previously by this cpu.`

But - what guarantees that sending the spurious interrupts takes more time than required for the APIC to re-route? 


Why is it not possible that we send spurious interrupts, the APIC won't finish the rerouting, and another interrupt will be sent to the original cpu, thus remains unhandled...

Comment: @NoamShalev I don't know. Either there is some deep internal reason why this is safe due to how the APIC is built or, and that would be my guess, it's just wrong but the person who wrote the code didn't think about it and the race condition window is so small he didn't see it in the tests and since the upstream code does do the mdelay() he never found out... :-)